# Inserting text in text area at current cursor position from keyboard as well as from programmer made keyboard in flex4?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex4.6

I am trying to insert text at current cursor position.I am able to insert text at current cursor position by keyboard but **not able to insert text by programmer made keyboard**.

Comment: Could you show your code?

Comment: yes sir.i have simply concatenate it.

Comment: protected function greekalpha_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
   {
    if(FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.textTarget.visible)
    { 
     
     
     FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.textTarget.text = FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.textTarget.text+ (event.target as Button).label;
    
      
    }
    
   }

Comment: what is programmer made keyboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
            var pos:int = taMain.selectionActivePosition;

            if (pos != -1)
            {
                taMain.text = taMain.text.substr(0, pos) + str + taMain.text.substr(pos, taMain.text.length - pos);
                taMain.selectRange(pos + str.length, pos + str.length);
            }
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>
```

Answer (score 0):

HI try with below code:-

```
protected function greekalpha_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {     
                if(FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.textTarget.visible) { 
                    FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.textTarget.setFocus(); 
                    FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.textTarget.insertText((event.target as Button).label); 
                } 
            }
```